# Proving a linear operator is compact: understanding the statement "norm limit of a sequence of finite rank operators".

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

I am having serious trouble understanding the proof that an operator is compact.

This is the original question I asked and the proof is included very helpfully in the answer.

[Show if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lambda_n=0$ then $Tu=\sum^\infty_{n=1} \lambda_n \langle u,e_n \rangle e_n$ defines a compact operator.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1768857/show-if-lim-n-to-infty-lambda-n-0-then-tu-sum-infty-n-1-lambda-n/1768888#1768888)

When showing the operator $T$ is compact the main criteria mentioned is "show $T$ is the norm limit of a sequence $T_n$ of finite rank operators".

> What does this statement mean?
>
> Do we have a finite rank operator?

Apologies if I am not asking the right question because I am not sure
 where to begin.

> In the proof, why do we have to show $$||T-T_k || \to 0$$
>
> Is it because this shows that $T$ is the limit of a sequence of finie
>   rank operators? So $T_k$ are the finite rank operators and $T$ is the limit?

Comment: Finite rank operators are compact and the subspace of compact operators is closed with respect to the operator norm.

Comment: In my case what is the operator norm?

Comment: $\|T\|_{\text{op}}=\sup\lbrace  \|T(x)\|_Y: x\in X,\, \|x\|_X\le 1\rbrace$ where $T:X\to Y$.

Comment: I thought this whole business of finite rank operators was to do with normed spaces or Banach spaces?

Comment: How did you get that as the operator norm?

Comment: This is the *definition*. Of course "finite rank" is an algebraic condition but *operator* means continuous linear map between Banach spaces.

Comment: The main problem is I don understand what $||T-T_k|| \to 0$ signifies in the grand scheme of things? Thanks you for your help, I have been struggling with this for a while

Comment: Also how do we know if we have a finite rank operator?

Comment: @jochen Regarding the comment finite rank, but we are in a Hilbert space?

Comment: The definition of $T$ suggests that we are in a Hilbert space. Otherwise, it is not necessarily true that a limit of  finite rank operators is a compact operator.

Comment: Your $T_k$'s from the previous question are all finite rank, because their image is spanned by $\{e_1, ..., e_k\}$.  Now $T_k \rightarrow T$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$, so $T$ is a limit of finite rank operators, and it's therefore compact.  $T$ itself won't be finite rank unless there are only finitely many nonzero $\lambda_n$.

Comment: @joshkeneda  How do you know that $T_k$ is spanned by $\{e_1,...,e_k\}$? is it because they are partial sums?

Comment: If an operator's *range* is finite-dimensional, we call it a finite rank operator.  What's the range of $T_k$?

Comment: @joshkeneda isnt that just $\{e_1,..,e_k\}$?

Comment: The range is a subspace of the span of $\{e_1, ..., e_k\}$, yeah.  In particular, it's finite-dimensional.

Comment: @joshkeneda I just have one last question, what is the operator norm? User jochen above in the comments said what it was but I am not sure what it is and what it means?

Comment: Do you have a reference book or something that you're working out of?  I suspect many of your troubles could be resolved by looking up definitions there.

In order to define something like "$T_k \rightarrow T$," we have to have some topology on the set of operators.  The operator norm gives us a topology to use.  Heuristically, the operator norm gives us an upper bound for the amount of stretching that a given operator does.  Try looking at the wikipedia pages on these topics or finding a reference text for more info.

Comment: @joshkeneda I am working out of class exercises and solutions