# Compactness of $Ax = \sum _{n=1} ^{\infty} \alpha_n \langle x,u_n \rangle u_n $ if $[\alpha_n]$ bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space having a countable orthonormal base $[u_1, u_2, \cdots]$. Also, suppose $Ax = \sum _{n=1} ^{\infty} \alpha_n \langle x,u_n \rangle u_n $, where $[\alpha_n]$ is a real bounded sequence. Is $A$ compact?

Now, I am familiar with the Spectral theorem, but that theorem starts with assuming that $A$ is indeed compact and also $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \alpha_n=0$. Here, we only know that the sequence $[\alpha_n]$ is bounded.

The problem, as described above, resembles yet another unanswered question here: [Show if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lambda_n=0$ then $Tu=\sum^\infty_{n=1} \lambda_n \langle u,e_n \rangle e_n$ defines a compact operator.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1768857/show-if-lim-n-to-infty-lambda-n-0-then-tu-sum-infty-n-1-lambda-n)

I began with the very definition of a compact operator: considered a bounded sequence $[x_n]$ in $X$ and tried to show that $Tx_n$ has a convergent subsequence. But that led to a very general sequence. Is this the right approach to the problem? I guess there must be an easy solution to this one as it almost entirely resembles the spectral theorem. I'd appreciate any hint/help.

Comment: Maybe you can try to write $A$ as a norm-limit of finite rank operators?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit? And in doing so, am I supposed to find $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \alpha_n =0$ as a condition for compactness, or, instead, only boundedness of $\alpha_n$s would suffice?

Comment: Suppose $\alpha_n = 1$, for all $n$. Then find a (very) simple formula for $Ax$. What does that tell you about $A$?

Comment: That $A=I, Ax=x = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty}<x,u_n>u_n$. And then it is not compact as it is not the norm limit of a *finite* rank operator. Am I right?

Comment: Wait, why do you think the identity is compact in an infinite dimensional Hilbert space? Consider, for example, the sequence $u_n$. This cannot have any (norm) convergent subsequence. indeed, the sequence $u_n$ converges *weakly* to zero, but $\Vert u_n \Vert = 1$ does not converge to zero, so $u_n$ does not converge (in norm) to zero. Thus it cannot converge in norm to anything (if it did, it would also converge weakly to that thing, but you can't have two distinct weak limits).

Comment: Thanks. (I edited that comment...)

Comment: Therefore, in the end, we do need vanishing $\alpha_n$s for compactness.

Comment: Yes, my argument didn't actually prove that, but it is true; it is possible to modify my argument slightly so that it works in general. If you look at the matrix representation for your operator in the basis $\{u_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, you will see that it is just a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots$. This operator is compact if and only if the diagonal entries converge to zero.

Answer (score 1):

In general A is not compact, take for example A = I, and $\alpha_n = 1$.
The confusion is in your notation, that is $$Ax = \sum _{n=1} ^{\infty} \alpha_n \langle x,u_n \rangle u_n$$. What does "=" mean here? If it meant norm convergence then A would be a limit of finite rank (hence compact) operators so it would be compact (this happens when $\alpha_n$ tends to $0$). But, I think the meaning of "=" is pointwise, i.e. for each $x$ the value of $Ax$ is the limit of the series. As remarked at the top this does not imply that $A$ is compact.